# Manipulating background-image radial transition not working in chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-transitions, transition

I've created a ripple effect out of purely css that had worked nicely before in all browsers, now it looks like it currently isn't working in chrome but correctly in other browsers (excluding I.E, I don't test that junk) Curious as to why this is happening? I've exhausted my resources as to what's happening now in chrome for it to now work.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn-shadow btn-ripple">Button</a>

[class^="btn"],
[class*=" btn"]
    display inline-flex
    font-family 'Roboto', sans-serif
    text-decoration none
    justify-content center
    align-items center
    text-align center
    cursor pointer
    white-space nowrap
    padding 8px 20px
    font-size 14px
    background-color white
    border-radius 2px
    color #434A54
    text-transform uppercase
    border none
    box-shadow 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24)
    transition all 0.4s ease-in-out
    background-position 50%
    outline none !important // we don't like outlines, nasty hobbits...
    &:before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        background: red;
    }
    &:not([disabled])
        &.btn-shadow
            &:active
                box-shadow 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.19), 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.23)
        &.btn-ripple
            transition all 0.4s ease-in-out
            background-size 200%
            &:active
                background-repeat no-repeat
                background-size 1000%
                background-image radial-gradient(circle, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 10%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 11%)
```

See it happening here:
http://codepen.io/brycesnyder/pen/gPojeO?editors=1100

Thanks!

Comment: `(excluding I.E, I don't test that junk)` LOL!! I laugh all the day. Maybe we achieve the same with the chrome junk, that is the new IE. I wish!!

Comment: That's not valid CSS. Is that less/sass/...?

Comment: @j08691 It's declarated as Stylus in the Codepen

Comment: [The codepen](http://codepen.io/brycesnyder/pen/gPojeO?editors=1100) works in my Chrome 52 the same way as my Firefox 48.  I see animated ripple and shadow effects.  Can you be more specific on what is not working?

Comment: Please take a look at my answer and mark it as the solution - if it helps :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is very interesting.

Looking at Firefox and Chrome I was able to reproduce what you desribed.

The simplest solution that came to me after reading the background-size [property docs in W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)

You forgot to define ***x*** and ***y*** dimensions of the new **background-size** value

Try this:

```
&.btn-ripple
    transition all 0.4s ease-in-out
    background-size 200% 200%
&:active
    background-repeat no-repeat
    background-size 1000% 1000%
```

Adding these values to the Codepen you attached I was able to see the transitions correctly in Chrome 51.

Hope this helps

Comment: Yup, `background-size` does not inherit *y* value from *x* if it is not defined, both values should be presented.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a bunch! I don't understand why it had worked previously, and it works in some browsers than suddenly it stopped. I got to a point where I was running in circles.